# Archive validation failed with errors

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, submission, itunes-store

I get the following error in XCode when submitting the app:

> Archive validation failed due the issues listed below.
>
> ITunes Store operation failed.
>
> Invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '1.1' is closed for new build submission.

But this version of my application is in the status of "Prepare for Submission" after the status "Developer rejected".
I want to upload a new Build to replace the existing, but can not do it.

Comment: We added a ".0" to the end of our display version and seemed to get past this error after rejecting & trying to re-upload.

Comment: @ericn so you created a new version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the version number in iTunes Connect and build another archive with that new version number. It will pass validation and you'll be able to submit.